# Kindle books (.azk) and iPad

Tags: ipad, apple-store, kindle, aws

I have the Kindle reader app for iPad and was just wondering the following:

1. What does a download link look like for an .azk/.azw file?
2. Where do the files get stored on the iPad once they are downloaded?

Comment: Why are you concerned about these things? The kindle app has a store where you can download our previous purchases as well as buy new books.

Comment: first off I am not concerned I am simply asking a question
secondly are you telling me that these files aren't stored on any of amazon's servers?

Comment: They are on Amazon's servers. What part of my comment makes you not think that? They're somewhere deep in an encrypted part of Amazon's kindle store servers. I really don't think it's possible to get a direct URL, but you may be able to download it by using Amazon.com and logging into your account

Comment: "The kindle app has a store where you can download our previous purchases as well as buy new books"

Comment: I've figured out my first problem anyway. now I need to know the file directory I need to access on my PC to see my downloaded files

Comment: Well you can't access your iPad's file system. But the Kindle app may allow iTunes file sharing